# Native query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

Good day, I have 3 tables which is **products**, **users**, and pivot **product_user** table.

and I want to fetch all the data in the main table if that row contains a pivot data.

Example

**products** table

```
ID    Name
1     sample 1----------> is in pivot table **product_user**
2     sample 2----------> is in pivot table **product_user**
3     sample 3
```

**users** table

```
ID     Name
1      user1-------------> is in the pivot table **product_user**
2      user2
3      user3-------------> is in the pivot table **product_user**
```

**product_user**

```
product_id    user_id
    1            1
    3            2
```

In this scenario how can I fetch the data in the two main table that contains pivot data?

How can I achieve the result of this query in laravel way?

```
SELECT p.`name`, u.`first_name`
FROM product_user AS pu
LEFT JOIN products AS p
    ON pu.`product_id` = p.id
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u
    ON pu.`user_id` = u.`id`
```

result

```
name             first_name
sample 1         user firstname
```

Comment: You can use `DB::raw(query) `

Answer (score 0):

You have a `BelongsToMany` relationship `Product` ↔ `User`:

```php
class ProductUser extends Model {

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}

$pivots = ProductUser::with('product', 'user')->get();
foreach($pivots as $pivot) {
    // $pivot->user->first_name
    // $pivot->product->name
}
```